# mysql variables are inconsistent

Tags: mysql

Just started out with MySQL 5.5 on Ubuntu Server 14.04 and ran into a strange issue.

I always show the settings of the variables by typing `mysql --help`.
Just to get familiar with MySQL-Server I wanted to change `local-infile` to true. So I went to `my.conf` of MySQL and under `mysqld` I added `local-infile = true`.

After restarting `MySQL-Server` I typed again `mysql --help` getting:

```
local-infile                      FALSE
```

By changing the client and server port from 3306 to 3305 I checked if the output of `mysql --help` is just a list of default setting but it is not.
The list now showed that the server is listening on 3305.

So I went into `mysql` typing

```
SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'local_infile'
```

getting following output

```
+---------------+-------+
| Variable_name | Value |
+---------------+-------+
| local_infile  | ON    |
+---------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

So why is the variable output inconsistent?

I hope this question is related to the database mysql and database administrators is the right place to ask this kind of question. I hope it is not directly related with Ubuntu. If so please bear with me.

Comment: Dit you put it in the `[mysqld]` section of my.cnf?

Comment: @Rick James yes, as mentioned in my question!

Answer (score 1):

**client (mysql) and server (mysqld) are different applications with different parameters**

- "mysql"  =  your mysql-client 'mysql' ... and that FALSE is the client parameter
- "/etc/init.d/mysql" =  name of the service that starts your mysql-server 'mysqld' that uses my.cfg for it's parameters

Comment: Ah you seem to be right. `mysql --help` seems to output the client-configuration and not the mysqld-service configuration. That is why it does not show up. And I am always using the client to interact with the server. I always thought I am on the server when fetching global variable `inline-file`, but I am using the client. Is this correct?